# How to mask the rightmost 16 bits of a 32-bit integer?

Tags: c

I am reading 32 bit integer values from a file. I need to read the rightmost 16 bits of each integer and divide each into 8 bit numbers.

The numbers I read from file: 1, 256, 32768, 32769, 128, 65534, 33153

I really appreciate your help to start on this project.

The code I am using right now is:

```
   unsigned result = (inputValue & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16
```

Comment: Can you please post some code with what have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: Also, you need to be more specific. "Rightmost" has different meanings depending on architecture. Are you on Intel, ARM, PPC, something else?

Comment: I am trying this in Intel, Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use bit masks. I'm assuming that "rightmost" means bits from 0 to 15. Then you could define macros like below (the quick solution):

```
#define GET_RIGHTMOST_16_BITS(x) ((x) & (unsigned int)0x0000FFFF)
#define GET_LOW_8_BITS(x) ((x) & (unsigned short)0xFF)
#define GET_HIGH_8_BITS(x) (((x) & ~((unsigned short)0xFF)) >> 8)
```

For more information, please read through bit operations in the book "The C Programming Language"

Comment: You should also right shift the result of `GET_HIGH_8_BITS` by 16 bits.

Comment: Yes exactly. I forgot that ... Actually right shift 8 bits.

Comment: Ya, right, it should be 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever one wants to work with explicit size integers in C, consider fixed width types.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t rightmost16bits(uint32_t i) {
  return (uint16_t) (i >> 16);
}

void divide_into8bit_numbers(uint16_t i, uint8_t *MSByte, uint16_t *LSByte) {
  *MSByte = (uint8_t) (i >> 8);
  *LSByte = (uint8_t) (i & 0xFF);
}

uint32_t i = fromfile();
uint16_t right = rightmost16bits(i);
uint8_t Numbers8Bit[2];
divide_into8bit_numbers(right, &Numbers8Bit[1], &Numbers8Bit[0]);
```